# Replacement for deprecated MediaQueryList.addListener() method

Tags: javascript, media-queries, deprecation-warning

The Mozilla Developers Network docs say `MediaQueryList.addListener()`  is deprecated.

Though it's working in my (Angular 8) code, the linting in VS Code is  warning about deprecation.

What's the replacement for `MediaQueryList.addListener()`?

Comment: The [MDN docs for addListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener) not only mention deprecation but also recommend the replacement: "Use `addEventListener()` instead of addListener() if it is available in the browsers you need to support."

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Quoting from the MDN docs about [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList):

> **`MediaQueryList.addListener()`** Adds a listener to the MediaQueryListener that will run a custom callback function in response to the media query status changing. This is basically an alias for `EventTarget.addEventListener()`, for backwards compatibility purposes.

`addEventListener` needs an event type as the first argument, so it becomes this:

```
// deprecated: MediaQueryList.addListener(listener);
MediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', listener);
```

The same stands true for `removeListener()`:

```
// deprecated: MediaQueryList.removeListener(listener);
MediaQueryList.removeEventListener('change', listener);
```

Comment: Please mind the compatibility table at MDN. One year later the new format is still not supported on Safari, I learned that the hard way :(

Comment: Here's a [link to the compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList#browser_compatibility) for those who want it, look for the "MediaQueryList inherits EventTarget" row. It's now supported from Safari 14 and upwards.

Answer (score 3):

Do this to ensure compatibility with browsers that do not support `MediaQueryList.addEventListener`:

```js
const darkModeQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')

if (darkModeQuery.addEventListener) {
  darkModeQuery.addEventListener('change', setDarkMode)
} else {
  darkModeQuery.addListener(setDarkMode)
}
```